# Decoupling feedback for testing of PWM controller IC for SMPS

Tags: pwm, switch-mode-power-supply

I am trying to test an SMPS controller IC (like KA3882) by isolating the controller from the PWM FET circuit and de-coupling the SMPS output (to optocoupler and the feedback pin of the controller).
By applying the required feedback voltage to the Vfb pin (2.5v in my case), I expect to get the square wave pulses on the output pin. **Is this procedure good enough**? I also felt that I-sense pin must be for protection against shorting of SMPS output power supply. Hence , **I skip applying a current to this pin, but I am not sure and need advice**.

**What is the purpose of I-Sense current in a PWM controller IC?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation surrounding the KA3882 is pretty poor compared to devices such as the UC3843 made again by Fairchild, ON semi and TI. So make a comparison: -

[image]

Make that comparison against the TI UC3843: -

[image]

You can also note that the pin numbers are the same and you can pretty much assume that functionally they are the same: -

[image]

> What is the purpose of I-Sense current in a PWM controller IC?

It's protection against too much current being fed through the inductor and it saturating excessively: -

[image]

So, to get more information functionally about the Fairchild KA3882 I'd look into the TI UC3842/3843 range of devices.

> I skip applying a current to this pin, but I am not sure and need
>   advice.

Don't apply a current input - it requires a voltage that represents current BUT, you can connect it to 0 volts for just a bench test.

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer. But what 0V at ISense pin signifies ? Will I see a pulse train at the ouput?

Comment: Yes, you will still see a pulse train - the Isense input is just to protect the inductor from overload currents and isn't necessary for the circuit to oscillate - Vfb pin will ensure that there will be oscillation close to it being at 2.5 volts - but take care - the open loop gain is high and it may produce 0% to 100% duty cycles on the output over a few millivolts change in Vfb AND it may be at 2.45 volts or as high as 2.55 volts (device dependent).

Comment: Do the totem output need a pull up resistor to see the pulse train 'cause  I'm seeing none?

Comment: No, it's a push-pull output but, it might help if you posted a schematic of your circuit. I might spot an error.